# Standard ML recursive function error

Tags: sml

So i just got in ML programming and I found this excercise in a book. The excercise says to build a recursive function that takes an integer and a list. If L=[a1,a2,a3] then the desired result is [ai+1,ai+2,...,an,a1,a2,...,ai]. So I wrote a function and after a lot of hours I narrowed the errors down to one which I can't understand. Here is my function:

```
fun cycle L i = 
    if i = 0 then L
    else (cycle tl(L) (i-1)) @ [hd(L)];
```

I will upload an image with the error that i get  so someone can explain to me what the interpreter is trying to say to me.

[image]

The numbers next to the "a" just show the order of these elements in the list.So for L=[1,2,3,4,5] and for i = 2, the desire result is the List L=[3,4,5,1,2]. I don't think that the type of list is essential in this problem. Hope this further explanation helped

Comment: Something must have gone lost in translation from this book, because nowhere in your description of the task does it say what *i* or *n* are, or how they relate to *a1*, *a2* and *a3*. Somehow *a1* comes after *an*. Can *L* be any type of list, or is it an int list? How many elements are in the result list; *n+?*. Maybe if you wrote the actual text of the assignment, or the name of the book and the numbering of the assignment, it might make more sense.

Comment: The numbers next to the "a" just show the order of these elements in the list.So for L=[1,2,3,4,5] and for i = 2, the desire result is the List L=[3,4,5,1,2]. I don't think that the type of list is essential in this problem. Hope this further explanation helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a syntactic problem with the recursive call `cycle tl(L) (i-1)`.

In SML, the syntax for function application is juxtaposition, not parentheses. In your case `tl(L)` indeed calls the function `tl` with argument `L`, but that's equivalent to just `tl L`. The parentheses are redundant and, as such, ignored.

Now, if you replace the minimal version within your original call, you'll get this: `cycle tl L (i-1)`. It's calling `cycle` with three arguments, instead of just two.

The correct way of writing it would be: `cycle (tl L) (i-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Ionuț already gave a sufficient answer to the syntax problem; here are some further suggestions:

1. Use pattern matching rather than `hd` and `tl`.
2. Consider the base cases; what are the simplest sub-problems you can think of? E.g. cycling the empty list will always give the empty list regardless of *n*, and cycling *L* 0 times will always give *L* back. Having both base cases as patterns helps.
3. Consider the recursive case; the top element (assuming it exists) is cycled and *i* is reduced by one, until eventually *i* is 0 or *L* is empty. Because the second base case catches the empty list, we can freely assume that *L* is non-empty here, in which case it will match the pattern `x::xs`.

   ```
   fun cycle 0 xs = xs
     | cycle i [] = []
     | cycle i (x::xs) = cycle (i-1) (xs @ [x])
   ```
4. Depending on whether `0 <= i` and `i <= length xs` are preconditions for the function or not, you may want to handle these once before activating the main recursion, e.g. by wrapping the function above:

   ```
   fun cycle i ys =
       let fun fun cycle' 0 xs = xs
                 | cycle' i [] = []
                 | cycle' i (x::xs) = cycle' (i-1) (xs @ [x])
       in
         if 0 <= i andalso i <= length xs
         then cycle' i ys
         else raise Domain
       end
   ```
5. The main operation, namely `xs @ [x]` is terribly inefficient, since its running time is proportional to the length of `xs` and is activated *n* times. So the running time of `cycle` becomes *O(n • |L|)* when something like *O(min(n,|L|))* should be achievable.

   You could probably make a much faster version if you store the cycled elements in a separate list, without using `@`, and combine the remaining elements with this list after the elements have been cycled. Depending on what you felt about `0 <= i` and `i <= length xs`, you may run into problems with the following test case:

   ```
   val cycle_test_1 = (cycle 5 [1,2,3,4] = [2,3,4,1])
   ```